# Simple way to read analog sensor

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a 5V ultrassonic sensor HC-SR04 and I want to read the value and (if > x) turns ON output 1 and turns OFF output 2  and (if < x) turns ON output 2 and turns off output 1.

Outputs are 24V so I would use a transistor or a relay to turn on the outputs with the arduino.

The only way I know is to use an Arduino. **But dont you think it's overkill? Is there a simple way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is an analog comparator (either made from discrete parts or a dedicated IC, an op-amp or a purpose built comparator), some resistors to set the switching threshold (or a voltage reference, e.g. a zener diode, for more accuracy), a FET or some other buffer with sufficient drive current to run a relay, a DPDT relay, and a flyback diode for the relay.

The arduino method eliminates the need for the comparator and allows you to set the trigger point in software rather than using resistors making the system a lot more flexible. The buffer and relay side of it are the same for both systems.

Both approaches have their pros and cons but ultimately it's probably best to go with whichever you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of an arduino in this case. You can do it with few transistors and one opamp to compare sensor's output to "x".

Arduino or µC are use to do complexe operation, read bus, compute some data... Yes it's possible to do it with an arduino but as you said, it's overkill.

If you look closer at the cost of your circuit, the design with arduino will be a way more expensive than the opamp (<1$)

Comment: I suppose it'll depend here on what equipment the OP already has and what they're quickest with.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use `Arduino`. `Ultrasonic.h` library is lifesaver, friendly! You can do this in a few lines on Arduino.

And also, You can use programmed pic like `PIC18F877A`. 
Either, You can research arduino-like products.

Comment: It's easier to use basic electronic than arduino in this case. Arduino is a good choice if @asdas wants to do some more complexe operation on the output.